# Update mysql row based on same ID condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql table (locations) that looks this:

locations

```
    +-------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
    | id    | street  | number | geoloc                                                      |
    +-------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 10    | street1 | 1      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.31231, 21.41241]}    |
    | 1000  | street2 | 2      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [9312.31231, 8231.41241]} |
    | 1000  | street2 | 2      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.45342, 21.44423]}    |
    | 10    | street1 | 1      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [312.31231, 33231.41241]} |
    | 10    | street1 | 1      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [4312.31231, 3231.41241]} |
    | 10000 | street3 | 3      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.31271, 21.41312]}    |
    +-------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now the problem is that some of the location's have wrong geoloc values, and the rule to filter wrong values/good values is that some x,y coordinates are valid (ex. -95.31231, 21.41241) and some don't (ex. 4312.31231, 3231.41241). The filter pattern for good values should be this format (-95.xxxxxx, 21.xxxxxx).

The end result after update should be exactly this:

locations

```
    +-------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
    | id    | street  | number | geoloc                                                      |
    +-------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 10    | street1 | 1      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.31231, 21.41241]}    |
    | 1000  | street2 | 2      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.45342, 21.44423]}    |
    | 1000  | street2 | 2      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.45342, 21.44423]}    |
    | 10    | street1 | 1      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.31231, 21.41241]}    |
    | 10    | street1 | 1      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.31231, 21.41241]}    |
    | 10000 | street3 | 3      |  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-95.31271, 21.41312]}    |
    +-------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
UPDATE locations l1, (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, geoloc
    FROM locations
    WHERE geoloc IS NOT NULL
) l2 SET l1.geoloc = l2.geoloc
WHERE l1.id = l2.id;
```

And I'm not sure that WHERE is actually matching by my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE locations l1, (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, geoloc <-- This will always return all rows
    FROM locations
    WHERE geoloc IS NOT NULL
) l2 SET l1.geoloc = l2.geoloc
WHERE l1.id = l2.id;
```

Also the update would be arbitrary.

You should try something like this.

```
UPDATE locations l1, locations l2
SET l1.geoloc = l2.geoloc
WHERE l1.id = l2.id
and l1. geoloc <> l2.geoloc
and ST_X(l2.geoloc) like '%-95.%';
```